# Multiple choice type question on inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $x$ be a positive real number. Then

$A.\ x^2+\pi ^2+x^{2\pi}>x\pi+(\pi+x)x^\pi$

$B.\ x^\pi+\pi^x>x^{2\pi}+\pi^{2x}$

$C.\ x^2+\pi ^2+x^{2\pi}<x\pi+(\pi+x)x^\pi$

$D.\ $none of the above

Which one is correct? And how to prove that?
Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's a hint: It's not B, because for x=0.5 the left side is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying various values of $x$.  The ones of interest seem to me to be very small, $1, \pi,$ very large.  For example if $x$ is very large the left side of A is dominated by $x^{2\pi}$ while the right side is dominated by $x^{(1+\pi)}$, so it is true.  B fails for $x=1$, so you can quit checking.  This may allow you to eliminate them all and choose D.  If any are left, you still need to prove it.

Comment: what is the correct option? $D$ ? how to prove that $A$ is not true?

Comment: I didn't say A is not true.  If you [plot it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2Bpi%5E2%2Bx%5E%282*pi%29-x*pi-%28pi%2Bx%29*x%5Epi) or [zoomed in](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%2Bpi%5E2%2Bx%5E%282*pi%29-x*pi-%28pi%2Bx%29*x%5Epi+from+1+to+2) it appears to be true, but close at $x=1.4$.  I haven't found a slick proof

Answer (score 0):

It can't be B or C, just let $x :=1.$
In A, for $~x=\pi~$ you get:$$\pi^2+\pi^{2\pi}>2\pi^{\pi+1},$$ which is true.

For x=1 you also get a true statement, but it's no proof for all positive reals.